# CakePHP saving models with similar data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have following code. I'm trying to make it simpler and shorter. I created `$data1` array and added relevant data with `array_merge` and saved it to my model. But note that `$data1` and `$exists` has same code inside. Is it possible to pass `$data1` array to MyModel's find method without rewriting same code ?

Because of I need to create multiple rows in these snippet, I used `MyModel->create`. In this code I pasted two blocks, but originally I have 6 blocks like this. So shortening is important for me.

As summary: 
I need to shorten this code snippet, I don't want to rewrite same data in each block.

```
        $usersNew=array("mike", "john");
        $usersLost=array("anna", "maria");

        $data1 = array('userid' => $userid,
            'date' =>  date('Y-m-d')
        );

        foreach ($usersNew as $f) {
            $data2 = array_merge($data1, array("users_new" => $f));
            $exists=$this->MyModel->find('first',
                array('conditions' => array(
                    'MyModel.userid' => $userid,
                    'MyModel.date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'MyModel.users_new' => $f
                ) ));

            if ($exists == FALSE) {
                $this->MyModel->create();
                $this->MyModel->save($data2);
            }
        }

        foreach ($usersLost as $f) {
            $data2 = array_merge($data1, array("users_lost" => $f));
            $exists=$this->MyModel->find('first',
                array('conditions' => array(
                    'MyModel.userid' => $userid,
                    'MyModel.date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'MyModel.users_lost' => $f
                ) ));

            if ($exists == FALSE) {
                $this->MyModel->create();
                $this->MyModel->save($data2);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimization of code, maybe this is not the best place to ask. There are other "siblings" of SO for that, like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'm just suggesting that because maybe you'll find better or more dedicated answers for that in there.

But, to the point at hand. What I normally do in a case like this is to have an extra array like this

```
$helper = array('usersNew'=>'users_new',
                'usersLost'=>'users_lost',
                /* name of array you want to loop => name of column in db */ );
```

It's like having an array of the variable part of your code. I'm using your exact code, but in case you need something more complicated in the future, a multidimensional array will be better.

So, you do just one `foreach` and go through all the variables in the `$helper` array

```
    $usersNew=array("mike", "john");
    $usersLost=array("anna", "maria");

    //I prefer to avoid merge performance, so I'm deleting this, though it works
    /*$data1 = array('userid' => $userid,
                   'date' =>  date('Y-m-d')
    );*/

    foreach ($helper as $arrayName => $dbCondition) {
        foreach ($$arrayName as $f) {
            $data = array('userid' => $userid,
                          'date' =>  date('Y-m-d'),
                          $dbCondition => $f
                     );
            $exists = $this->MyModel->find('first',
                                     array('conditions' => array(
                                                 'MyModel.userid' => $userid,
                                                 'MyModel.date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                                 'MyModel.'.$dbCondition => $f
                      ) ));


            if ($exists == FALSE) {
                $this->MyModel->create();
                $this->MyModel->save($data);
            }

       }
   }
```

I haven't test the code, but it should work without mayor modifications, maybe a closing } I'm missing or something like that.

If for some reason, this piece of code gives you problems (happens to me sometimes)

```
$data = array('userid' => $userid,
                      'date' =>  date('Y-m-d'),
                      $dbCondition => $f
                 );
```

do it in two parts

```
$data = array('userid' => $userid,
                      'date' =>  date('Y-m-d'),
                 );
$data[$dbCondition] = $f;
```

The trick is the double `$$` ([variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)) and organize the `$helper` array in a way that works for you. I hope I made this clear enough.

Comment: Also thank you for Code Review link. I didn't know that site.